# java: No Endpoint found, but python works

Tags: java, python, usb, libusb

I want to try out the java libusb from http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net and cant even connect to my device...

I had this python code before:

```
def discover():
    my_device = None
    for bus in usb.busses():
        for dev in bus.devices:
            if dev.idVendor == 0x16c0 and dev.idProduct == 0x05dc:
                handle = dev.open()
```

which worked really great. now i wanted to build the same in java and made this:

```
Device dev = USB.getDevice((short) 0x16c0, (short) 0x05dc);
try {
    dev.open(1, 0, -1);

} catch (USBException e) {
    }
```

but all i get now is

```
ch.ntb.usb.USBException: No USB endpoints found. Check the device configuration
    at ch.ntb.usb.Device.updateMaxPacketSize(Device.java:82)
    at ch.ntb.usb.Device.initDevice(Device.java:114)
    at ch.ntb.usb.Device.open(Device.java:194)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

that cant be true because i double checked the values from `lsusb` and i have a Configuration 1 and an Interface 0...
Whats could be so difficult to connect to my device? I dont get it...

Comment: You scan busses and devices on busses in your python code -- does the equivalent Java code also work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the device only had an interrupt endpoint, which is reachable for the python implementation but not for the java one... I changed that and now it works!

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've the same problem, what did you change?

Comment: Could you help me over here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129112/interfacing-a-libusb-device-powered-by-v-usb-library-for-avr